# How to fix Fortify "Dynamic Code Evaluation: Script Injection" error

Tags: javascript, jquery, fortify

How to Fix fortify Dynamic Code Evaluation: Script Injection error?

```
onCommentSuccess: function (showAllComments) {
  $('#commentListDiv').load(location.href + ' #commentListDiv', function() {
    ACC.quote.displayComments('' + showAllComments);
  });
```

Getting Error as

> Read location.href() & ~JS_Generic.load()

Comment: Is that a warning or an error? There's nothing inherently wrong about what you're doing - aside from concatenating an empty string to a string. That can be removed.

Comment: @Rory McCrossan: That is an error when we run Fortify Tool. Also what can be removed could you please explain in brief?

Comment: I mean that you don't need to concatenate the empty string to the variable to coerce its data type, just do `ACC.quote.displayComments(showAllComments);`